# Xcode exc_bad_access when returning to app (spritekit game, swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, exc-bad-access

i'm working on a game using Swift and SpriteKit.

my App is pretty much complete, but now i have a nasty bug.
i'm testing on multiple devices and this error is ONLY showing up on older devices. - iPhone 4s, iPod touch 5th Gen

but, works fine on iPhone 6S Plus and iPad Air 2.

all systems running same iOS 9.3.2
Xcode 7.3.1

when i exit my game, using home button, then go back into the game play, an EXC BAD ACCESS Code 1 is thrown on the sprite that should be shown.

This does not happen on newer devices, only the older ones.
I am guessing that the older devices have less RAM and so are more strict on deallocating objects??

is there a way i can force the object in question to not be deallocated until I say it can be ? as in - leave the scene - but not when user exits app (because they may come back to it)

thanks for any pointers, i have of course been googling this all evening...

is it something to do with 32bit/64bit?? can't really see how

Comment: Try setting an 'All Exceptions' breakpoint to see if you get a more useful stack trace

Comment: there's this: objc_object::sidetable_release(bool)

Comment: which tells me absolutely nothing useful.

Comment: Objects should not be deallocated if you have a strong pointer to them, regardless of memory availability. iOS should either leave your objects alone or terminate the app (after a memory warning notification). Are you implementing state preservation/restoration? The app is more likely to be terminated on lower memory devices so if your restoration code is broken that may explain the different behaviour.

Comment: hi thanks for that.  no, not using state preservation/restoration.  haven't needed to and i am not sure if that would work for a spritekit game.

Comment: i've been testing on real devices, but i just checked and this same behaviour happens in the simulator.  simulated 4S crashes while a simulated 5S doesn't.  most odd.

Comment: it seems to be all about timing.  if a game element is spawned just as the game comes back into being active, it crashes, if i hit a lucky sweet spot, it runs normal.  Still only happening on older devices, but this is some progress - i've tried introducing a delay on the pause that is called by NSNotificationCenter when AppDelegate resumes but this again, only works sometimes..  this is very frustrating.

Comment: i get this when i hover over the error:   error loading helper function: Trying to put the stack in unreadable memory at: 0xfec97e7c.